# referencing com interface in fsi F# interactive

Tags: f#, com-interop, fsi, com-interface

I'm trying to rewrite [this](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-a-c-client.html) matlab `.Net` example in F# interactive. 
In the example a COM-interface reference is used. 
How do I reference a COM-interface from within the fsi?

EDIT

I refence the as described

> From the Project menu, select Add Reference. Select the COM tab in the Add Reference dialog box. Select the MATLAB application.

This reference I can not send with right click to the interactive. There is no path in the properties and the dll cited in the description MLApp.dll I can not find in my matlab directory. This F# programm works:

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let matlab = new MLApp.MLAppClass()
    matlab.Execute "x=1+1"          |> printfn "%A"
    matlab.GetVariable("x","base")  |> printfn "%A"
    0
```

But I want to use it from *FSI*.

Comment: Don't post direct links to other resources. If you want to refer to information from other resource, better to copy it in the questions, so other developers can read a question without navigating to other links. Thanks.

Comment: If you referenced it in VS you can right click and select send reference to FSI. Or specify with #r  the dll path.

Comment: The same way you reference any other dll in fsi

Comment: I there any problem with doing [this](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/call-matlab-function-from-c-client.html)?

Comment: @ ghaiklor I hope with the edit it is bettern now.

Comment: @ s952163 this works for dll but I do not refrence a dll, I can compile and run code referencing the running application. I want to reference it from the FSI.

Comment: @John-Palmer if I knew a dll I would, but in VS Studio it works fine to reference a running apllication, and I want to do it in the FSI.

Comment: The build output should give you the actual path to the referenced dll

Comment: @PeterSiebke In case you don't get a workable solution I'll take a look tomorrow (as I'd need access to matlab).

Comment: Look in the bin\Debug directory of that little test project you used.  There should be an interop library for matlab, auto-generated when you built the program.  You might want to copy it into a better directory.  Use #r in the fsi console to reference it.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you for your solution, it solves my needs, but I' still curios if there could be a solution without the auto generated dll of a (different) project.

Comment: You can also run Tlbimp.exe to generate the interop library.  Having the IDE do it for you helps you avoid learning how to use it, rather the point of using an IDE.  There is no fundamental difference.